# How to make "watch" task forever false?

Tags: reactjs, npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, netlify

I am trying to deploy a static website from bitbucket to Netlify. It fails because "watch" is in waiting mode.

The logs from Netlify:

```
Done, without errors.
8:38:52 PM: Completed in 60.606s at Fri Dec 08 2017 17:38:43 GMT+0000 (UTC) - Waiting...
```

My Gruntfile.js configuration is:

```js
watch: {
      options: {
         livereload: true,
         atBegin: true,
         interval: 1000,
         forever: false,
         // spawn: false,
         // interrupt: true,
         // debounceDelay: 3000
        },
```

Help me to make "watch" task end after building.

Comment: There's a fair bit of information missing in your question, but primarily: why do you even need `watch` if you want to deploy a static site? If it's a proper static site, you build the content, then copy it over; there should be no continuously running process.

Comment: Why do you use the `watch` task if you don't _want_ to watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments above, there needs to be some more information in your question about your config.

There needs to be a `build` target in the grunt config that does not use the local development server as watch is doing.

```js
watch: {
  ....
},
build: {
  ....
}
```

Also you would need to register the task as in the following command:

```js
grunt.registerTask('build', ['target1', 'target2']);
```

Then the build command in Netlify would be: `grunt build` rather than the command you are using.